# is it possible to include files in the touch UI dialog?

Tags: xml, aem

is it possible to include files in a touch UI dialog? I understand how to include a file inside the classic UI dialog which I've gave an example below. Is this possible for Touch UI dialog if so how do I accomplish this?

```
<livecopy
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    path="/apps/stackoverflow/components/page/page/tab_stackoverflow.infinity.json"
    xtype="cqinclude"/>
```

Comment: To be fair, this does not really include a file. It allows the dialog to download a JSON document describing the tab. The JSON document itself is just a representation of a tree of JCR Nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use the resource type `granite/ui/components/foundation/include` to do similar operation in Touch UI.

```
<livecopy
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    path="/apps/stackoverflow/components/page/page/tab_stackoverflow"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"/>
```

For more information check the [ExtJS vs matching Granite UI components](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/the-basics/touch-ui-concepts.html#ExtJS%20vs%20matching%20Granite%20UI%20components) topic and the [Granite Include documentation](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/include/index.html).